# Investigate a queue with linked lists in java

Tags: java

*.. I have to use a piece of code in java but I don't understand some parts of it.*

The code uses methods *(.isEmpty() etc. )* from a simple Queue i made in another document.

It is suppposed to investigate an array (which has linked lists in each address) and do *some sort of processing with its values.*

The problem is that i dont know what **marked[s] = true;** ,**marked[t.v] = true;** and **parent[t.v] = k;** are and how do they work as variables (?)

```
void BFS(int s) 
{
     Queue<Integer> Q = new Queue<Integer>();  
     marked[s] = true;
     Q.put(s);
     while (!Q.isEmpty())
     {
         k = Q.get();
         for (Node t = adj[k]; t != null; t = t.next)
             if (!marked[t.v]) {
                 marked[t.v] = true;
                 parent[t.v] = k;
                 Q.put(t.v); 
             }
         }
     }
}
```

edit: I wrote matrix instead of array, sorry.

Comment: `marked` and `parent` are [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). The value within the brackets denot the index, which is set/read. As for the semantics of this program: maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) helps.

Comment: that makes sense but why it uses marked[s] and then marked[t.v] , it is like it is a 2 dimensional matrix in marked[t.v]. Thanks , i will check it out.

Comment: No, not a 2D matrix at all.  That would be more like marked[row][col].

Comment: i see, my mistake , so is it possible that t.v is a reference to the linked list in the matrix adj[]?

Comment: @Bill `marked[t.v]` means "get the value of `t.v` (which must be an `int`) and use it as the index for the array access".

Comment: @Bill `adj[]` is an _array_, not a _matrix_. `t` as you can see from the code, is  a `Node` object. That node object will have a member variable called `v`. `t.v` therefore fetches the value of the variable `v` in the Node object `t`.

Comment: sure , but why .v after t?

Comment: @KLibby yeah i got confused , it is an array.

Comment: @Bill It seems that you do not quite got the concept about objects. Maybe you should take a step back and read a tutorial. To solve your problem, you may want to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/), but to fully understand the concepts, you should [start from the beginning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: @KLibby ok i got that !

Comment: @Turing85 i am a begginer indeed but in complicated projects i get confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`marked[]` `parent` and `adj` are all arrays.

`t` as you can see from the code, is a `Node` object. That node object will have a member variable called `v`. `t.v` therefore fetches the value of the variable `v` in the `Node` object `t`.

`marked[t.v]` finds the element in the array with index equal to `t.v`. e.g. if `t.v` is equal to 0, then you are fetching `marked[0]` which is the first element in the `marked` array.